# SQL Conditional loses NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, conditional-statements

I am using SQL server 2005.  I have a variable @var that can take values 0, 1, or NULL.  I care about it being 1 or not, 0 and NULL are the same for me.  But when I set it to be not 1, I lose the NULL values:

```
DECLARE @var INT
SET     @var = NULL

IF @var <> 1
    PRINT 'not 1'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'equals 1'
```

The output is "equals 1". What would be the correct code to get "not 1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `coalesce` for this:

```
if coalesce(@var, 0) <> 1
    PRINT 'not 1'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'equals 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF @var = 1
    PRINT 'equals 1'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'not 1'
```

or

```
IF @var <> 1 or @var is null
    PRINT 'not 1'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'equals 1'
```

since comparing to `null` results in *unknown* which is not *true*. Use the `IS` operator for `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare to NULL, this is the property that is set by using directive

```
SET ANSI-NULLS OFF
```

More on that can be seen [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) :

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>)
>   comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A SELECT
>   statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that
>   have null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name <> NULL returns the rows that have nonnull values in the
>   column. Also, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <>
>   XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not
>   NULL.

However, this flag is deprecated and you shouldn't really use it.

Correct way here would be

```
IF @var IS NULL OR @var <> 1
    PRINT 'not 1'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'equals 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL means unknown, so SQL Server can't say with 100% certainty that it's not 1.  On the other hand if you had "IF @val = 1" then it would say that it can't be certain that it is 1 and move to your ELSE statement.

The COALESCE and ISNULL solutions will work for you by converting the NULL value to a known value, but it's important to know why it's working the way it is.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)